# running unity game with flutter

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine

So me and my team is working on a game idea for a hackathon we have made the game in 2 parts in unity and have made frontend with flutter and backend with firebase,
we are lost how to use the game in flutter.
we have exported the project of unity using `flutter_unity_widge` but we don't know how we can combine both games and what can we do to run the game.
also the build fails when we try to deploy it on  emulator

[error shown when build fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmFcY.png)

I tried to export the files again.
error

```
launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Warning: The plugin cloud_firestore requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin firebase_auth requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin firebase_core requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin path_provider_android requires Android SDK version 33.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to D:\flutter projects\celeste\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
}


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_unity_widget' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_unity_widget/flutter_unity_widget.dart';

class UnityScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const UnityScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _UnityScreenState createState() => _UnityScreenState();
}

class _UnityScreenState extends State<UnityScreen> {
  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  late UnityWidgetController _unityWidgetController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              UnityWidget(
                onUnityCreated: onUnityCreated,
                onUnityMessage: onUnityMessage,
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 20,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 10,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        OutlinedButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => changeCurrentLevel("Level1"),
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_rounded),
                            label: const Text("Level 1")),
                        OutlinedButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => changeCurrentLevel("Level2"),
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_rounded),
                            label: const Text("Level 2")),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  // Callback that connects the created controller to the unity controller
  void onUnityCreated(controller) {
    _unityWidgetController = controller;
  }

  void onUnityMessage(message) {
    print('Received message from unity: ${message.toString()}');
  }

  changeCurrentLevel(String value) {
    _unityWidgetController.postMessage(
      'LevelController',
      'ChangeCurrentLevel',
      value,
    );
  }
}
```

this is just of the unity screen

edit
did all that the 1st ans asked too

error still exists

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_unity_widget:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_unity_widget:androidApis'.
   > Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar.
         > C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             13.7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Update dependency based upon your flutter version

in pubspec.yaml:

If Flutter >3.0.0

```
dependencies:
  flutter_unity_widget: ^2022.2.0
```

Pre Flutter <3.0.0 (This version will gradually be deprecated)

```
dependencies:
  flutter_unity_widget: ^2022.1.0+7
```

As mentioned in error change complied sdk verion in `android\app\build.gradle` to this

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
}
```

Comment: i have new error i have updated that in me Q pls see

Comment: uninstall and reinstall android sdk in android studio. Flutter is not finding sdk properly.